# How do I get Scala's Option class so I can pass it to getDeclaredMethod()

Tags: scala, generics

I'm trying to get the `classOf[the-abstract-class-Option]`, but instead I always get the `classOf[the-Option-*object*]`. How can I get *the class of the abstract class* instead?

Both `Option.getClass` and `classOf[Option[_]]` gives me `class scala.Option$`.

**Edit:** I needn't have asked this; all of a sudden, `classOf[Option[_]]` works fine, weird. **/Edit**

**Background:**

I'm trying to invoke via reflection a method that takes an `Option[String]` parameter.
It signature look like so: `...(..., anySectionId: Option[String], ...)...`
Before I can invoke the method, I look it up via `getDeclaredMethod`. But to do that, I need a list of parameter types, which I construct by calling `_.getClass` on each argument I'm going to give to the method. But `_.getClass` returns `classOf[None]` or `classOf[Some]` for Option instances, which makes `getDeclaredMethod` fail, because (?) the signature is based on Option not Some/None.

Here's the code:

```
val clazz: Class[_] = Play.current.classloader.loadClass(className)

val paramTypes = arguments.map(_ match {
  case None => Option.getClass  // gives me the object, not the abstract class
  case _: Some[_] => classOf[Option[_]]  // this also gives me the object  :-(
  case x => x.getClass  // results in None or Some for Option instances
})

val m: jl.reflect.Method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("apply", paramTypes: _*)
```

and the last line above fails for a method with any `Option` parameter (otherwise everything works fine).

Comment: I hate it when that happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is use Scala reflection.

The next best way is not to make work for yourself by trying to match the param types.

Using `getClass` fails for subtypes:

```
scala> class Foo
defined class Foo

scala> class Bar extends Foo
defined class Bar

scala> class Baz { def baz(f: Foo) = 1 }
defined class Baz

scala> val b = new Baz
b: Baz = Baz@d33eaa9

scala> val p = new Bar
p: Bar = Bar@406c5ca2

scala> classOf[Baz].getDeclaredMethod("baz", p.getClass)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Baz.baz(Bar)
```

It's easier just to match on the name:

```
scala> classOf[Baz].getMethods.find(_.getName == "baz") map (_.invoke(b,p)) getOrElse -1
res5: Any = 1
```

or filter on the number of params for poor man's overloading resolution, then maybe filter on all args having conforming types.

The notation for accidentally getting the object is in fact:

```
scala> classOf[Option$]
res8: Class[Option$] = class scala.Option$
```

Comment: Thanks! This is simpler. Now my code looks like so: `viewClass.getMethods.find(_.getName == "apply") getOrDie "DwE74hG0X3"`.

Answer (score 1):

Answer:  `classOf[Option[_]]`

Weird! Suddenly  `classOf[Option[_]]` works. I feel sure I tested once or twice before I submitted the question :-(   Perhaps the IDE didn't have time to save the file before I recompiled, weird.

I don't know if I should delete the question. Or perhaps I should leave it as is, in case `classOf[Option[_]]` isn't obvious to everyone.